# How do I add a link to the menu that has a charector (?) in it?

Tags: menus, links

I'm trying to add a link to a drop-down menu but it gets lopped off every time.  THe full address is https://www.ub-tonlinebank.com/onlineserv/HB/Login.cgi?runmode=REGISTRATION but is stops at ? and gives an error when pulled up via WordPress.  I tried getting around this by creating a bit.ly link but still get the same problem.  How can I link to the whole address?  thanks![image]

Comment: What drop-down menu are you referring to? Drop-downs are theme specific.

Comment: This is a modified template of twenty-ten and the standard Menus under Appearance.

Comment: Can [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/109371/edit) to show (or explain) how you are adding the link?

Comment: Just going into the standard Menus under Appearance and pasting the link into the Custom Link field.  I'll add a screen shot to the initial question too.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?